# Invalid (private) key when connecting to Snowflake in Metabase

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, metabase

I'm running Metabase in a docker on a webserver. I'm trying to configure a connection to snowflake in the UI.

I generated my (working) pkcs8 keys in the following way;

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -m pkcs8 -f <keyname>
ssh-keygen -e -f <keyname>.pub -m pkcs8
```

I added a passphrase (however I can also delete this passphrase in case needed).

When connecting I upload the privatekey . However I get the following error;

```
Private key provided is invalid or not supported: /tmp/metabase-secret_5674679400356432530.tmp: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DER input, Integer tag error
```

When removing the password and trying it again I get the following;

```
Private key provided is invalid or not supported: /tmp/metabase-secret_12738717729576368567.tmp: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance, I'm really looking forward to use Metabase with my Snowflake data!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, even though the UI in Snowflake says it requires PKCS8, when I convert it to .pem (rsa) it works;

```
openssl rsa -in <keyname> -out rsa_key.pem
```